# Having trouble getting Fabric to upload my build

Tags: ios, twitter-fabric

I recently installed Fabric (Version 2.5.4 (1212)) and everything worked great until I got to the point where I tried to distribute a build.  The Fabric app for OS X just hangs on the "uploading" screen, showing the spinner indefinitely.

I also tried using the command line tool w/ debug output as recommended by Frabric support and this is the output I got:

```
2016-09-10 09:14:32.191 submit Crashlytics: Crashlytics.framework/submit 1.3.5 (18)
2016-09-10 09:14:32.196 submit Crashlytics: Path to IPA manually provided: Bizzy - Dev.ipa
2016-09-10 09:14:32.598 submit Crashlytics: Path To App: /var/folders/ft/jv8pcp6d6t31_p2807l75sc80000gp/T/Bizzy - Dev/Payload/Bizzy.app
2016-09-10 09:14:35.995 submit Crashlytics: Added Testers/Groups Successfully 200
2016-09-10 09:14:36.000 submit Crashlytics: Submitting IPA at /var/folders/ft/jv8pcp6d6t31_p2807l75sc80000gp/T/com.crashlytics.mac/distributions/04F98A41-A6FC-47F4-95E5-C0CC208EB7D4.ipa
2016-09-10 09:41:54.662 submit Crashlytics: Unable to submit build. Response code: 0
2016-09-10 09:41:54.690 submit Crashlytics: Failed to upload binary
```

I have no idea what is going on.  I've used Crashlytics in the past to distribute betas without any issue but now it refuses to upload my beta builds.  FWIW I can't think of anything special about this particular IPA.  Support says they are looking into it but I was hoping to get this resolved sooner than later and I did not hear back from them all day yesterday - if I get an answer I will share it here.

Has anyone seen this before and, if so, have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm running into a similar issue, apart from the Fabric app is able to upload the binary successfully, but the Post-actions on the Archive is not.

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to resolve the issue myself, their support never provided a resolution, and I abandoned fabric shortly afterward.

Comment: Thanks for the response. 

For me, it eventually resolved itself - I'm not sure exactly what it was, but it appears that it was most probably a bad network connection because it resumed working some time later... Of course only after I had dedicated many hours that day trying to find a solution (since other network related stuff didn't seem interrupted by bad connectivity). 

I think both the response code and error message should really have been more obvious assuming it was network connectivity that was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had an identical error, for me it was caused by a different computer on my network using all the upload-bandwidth. Once I ceased the other upload, I was able to submit the binary to Crashlytics.